# How to infer generic in a curried function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type out an API for querying collections. I want it to be used like so:

```
interface Car {
  model: string
  doors: 2 | 4 | 5
  designers: string[]
}

const result = query({
  model: [ contains('tesla') ],
  doors: [ is(3) ],
  designers: [ includes('Franz') ],
  take: 5,
});
```

So here's my imperfect approach:

```
type Query<Entity extends EntityType> = (config: QueryConfig<Entity>) => Promise<Entity[]>
type QueryConfig<Entity extends EntityType> =
  { [K in FilterScalarMembers<Entity>]?: ScalarBuilderFn<Entity[K]>[] }
  & { [K in FilterCollectionMembers<Entity>]?: CollectionBuilderFn<Entity[K]>[] }
  & { take: number };

type FilterCollectionMembers<Entity extends EntityType> =
  { [K in keyof Entity]: Entity[K] extends CollectionType ? K : never }[keyof Entity]

type FilterScalarMembers<Entity extends EntityType> =
  { [k in keyof Entity]: Entity[k] extends (string | number) ? k : never }[keyof Entity]

type ScalarBuilderFn<T extends string | number> = (builder: ScalarQueryBuilder<T>) => ScalarQueryBuilder<T>
type CollectionBuilderFn<T extends CollectionType> = (builder: CollectionQueryBuilder<T>) => CollectionQueryBuilder<T>
type ScalarQueryBuilder<T extends string | number> = {}
type CollectionQueryBuilder<T extends CollectionType> = {}
type EntityType = Record<string, any>
type CollectionType = ((string | number)[]) | Set<string | number>

const is = <T extends string | number>(arg: T): ScalarBuilderFn<T> => function() {} as unknown as ScalarBuilderFn<T>;
```

The problem becomes apparent here: `doors: [ is(3) ]` as the type didn't get narrowed to `2 | 4 | 5`, TypeScript doesn't give out an error about the `3` argument. Can we do something to the `is` function to help it infer the type correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [indexed types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```
const result = query({
    doors: [is<Car['doors']>(3)]
});
```

You can pass `is` a generic parameter of `Car['doors']` which will tell `is` that its parameter has to be assignable to `Car['doors']`, namely `2 | 4 | 5`.

I'm not sure you need all of those types then - unless they do other things not shown here. All you need is for `is` to have one generic type parameter which its parameter needs to match

```
const is = <T>(val: T) => { } // rest of the implementation
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I want the `is` argument type to be inferred from the context of where `is` is being used. Specifying the generic type by hand is error prone.